Duplicate user records in Firebase / Google Cloud Project with the same e-mail address
We have a Firebase/GCP project with multi-tenancy enabled. (It's a web site.)
One of the tenants have multiple user accounts with the same e-mail address.
Different Ids, but same email addresses.
One of the users managed to create 9 different accounts with the same-email address.
I've checked IP addresses (for different accounts) just in case to check if they're the same. Which it isn't.
According to google;

A user cannot directly create multiple accounts with the same email
address on Firebase by default; the platform is designed to prevent
this, as each email address should be associated with only one user
account; however, you can potentially achieve a similar effect by
using different sign-in methods (like Google Sign-in and
email/password) with the same email address, effectively creating
separate user profiles under the same email depending on the sign-in
method used.


If there is only one identity provider is active, how could this be happening?

Here is part from the sign up code block;
    /**
    * @type {import('firebase/auth').UserCredential}
    */
    const userRecord = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch(
                (error) => {
                    return error;
                }
            );
            userId = userRecord?.user?.uid;
    
            // @ts-ignore
            if (userRecord?.code) {
                // @ts-ignore
                return statusCallback({ submitting: false, code: userRecord.code, error: true });
            }
    
            //Set User Records On Server
            delete formObject.password;
    
            //# Update User with displayname
            const userUpdate = await updateProfile(userRecord.user, { displayName: username });
        
            let token = await userRecord.user.getIdToken(false);
            const parsedToken = parseJwtClient(token);
    
            // Get updated token. If needed.
            if (parsedToken?.['https://hasura.io/jwt/claims']) {
                token = await getLoginToken(userRecord);
            }
    
            if (!token) {
                signOutGA();
                return statusCallback({
                    submitting: false,
                    code: 'auth/invalid-oauth-provider',
                    error: true
                });
            }
    
            // Prepare data for API call
            const postData = { user: formObject, guser: userRecord.user };
    
            // Send data to register API
            const result = await request('/api/register', 'POST', postData, token).then((response) =>
                response.json()
            );
    
            if (result?.error || result?.code) {
                if (auth.currentUser) {
                    await deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
                }
                return signupError(result, statusCallback);
            }
    
            // Set JWT token
            jwtToken.set(() => token);
    
            // Fetch user data
            const user = await fetchUser(token);
    
            // Set player data
            player.set(user);


Naturally database only accepts one record with the same email address, I'm not sure which account is returning from Google. Users claims (I've tested) they get "wrong password" error. If they manage to login they can't retrieve data from our system because logged-in user's id in the JWT token isn't the same with the db record.
This scenario happened 4 or 5 times in total. I'm not sure what to look for.
Additional Information;

Registration data is collected via form on a Svelte Page.
Data submission function is triggered on button click, not a submit.
On form submit, page access & submit button are both disabled/limited.
There are 10k+ users, yet only a couple of users had this issue on different times.

Isn't Google supposed to handle this?

While you've shown us a portion of the sign up code, this doesn't show how this code could have been called multiple times. We need more information on how this code is triggered. Is it from clicking a submit button on a form? Is it accidentally from a react style hook or render? Please edit this into your question. All of the users you listed above have the same created timestamp. This implies that the "create user request" was rapidly sent to multiple edge servers and they all received the request, got a no answer to "does this email already exist?", and then dutifully created the new user.

Is "Link accounts that use the same email" set at https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME/authentication/settings

@RonnieSmith It's already set as that option.
